# VBA CustomUI activate or deactivate control

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

activating and deactivating a button on the excel ribbon

This code VBA return error in "Actualise_CTRL process".

`objRuban.InvalidateControl "Bouton1"`

Erro 91
variable or block object with undefined

the html code is lower

I've been stuck on this topic since this afternoon. In principle this set of code should enable or disable control of the custom tab of the EXCEL ribbon, but there must be something I'm missing.

Thanks a lot for any help on the subject

```
Option Explicit

Public objRuban As IRibbonUI
 boolResult As Boolean


'Callback for customUI.onLoad
'Est déclenché lors du chargement du ruban personnalisé.
Sub RubanCharge(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
   boolResult = False
   Set objRuban = ribbon
End Sub


'Callback for Bouton1 onAction
'La procédure déclenchée lorsque vous cliquez sur le bouton.
Sub ProcLancement(control As IRibbonControl)
   MsgBox "ma procédure."
End Sub


'Callback for Bouton1 getEnabled
'Active ou désactive le bouton en fonction de la variable boolResult
Sub Bouton1_Enabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = boolResult
End Sub


Sub Actualise_CTRL(ByVal Target As Range)

'Vérifie si la cellule A1 est modifiée et si la cellule contient la valeur 1.
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Target = 1 Then
       boolResult = True
   Else
       boolResult = False
    End If
        
'Rafraichit le bouton personnalisé

    
   objRuban.InvalidateControl "Bouton1"

End Sub
```

The ribbon XML:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">


    
<!-- Indiquez True pour masquer tous les autres onglets standards-->
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    
    <tabs>

<tab id="OngletPerso" label="OngletPerso" visible="true">
   <group id="Projet01" label="Projet 01">

      <!-- onAction="ProcLancement" définit la macro déclenchée lorsque vos cliquez sur le bouton. -->
      <!-- getEnabled="Bouton1_Enabled" gére la condition d'activation ou de désactivation. -->       
     <button id="Bouton1" label="Lancement" onAction="ProcLancement" size="normal" 
         imageMso="Repeat" getEnabled="Bouton1_Enabled"/> 

   </group>
</tab>

</tabs>

</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Does this error occur every time or does it run without error some times? (if the code is paused/restarted you may be losing your reference to IRibbonUI, causing this error)

Comment: You need to add the `onLoad` callback to the ribbon XML markup. See my answer posted for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialize the `objRuban` instance in the code you need to handle the `onLoad` callback of your ribbon XML.

So, in your ribbon XML markup you need to add the following attribute:

```
<customUI … onLoad="RubanCharge" …>
```

And then in the code you may rely on the `objRuban` instance initialized correctly.

You may find the [Dynamically updating the ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/overview-of-the-office-fluent-ribbon#dynamically-updating-the-ribbon) section helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I used to make sure the reference to the Ribbon (Ribbon in my code, objRuban in yours) is maintained.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (destination As Any, source As Any, ByVal length As Long)

Private Ribbon As IRibbonUI

' instance check/fix - if ribbon object is Nothing, attempt to load stored reference
Public Sub getRibbon()
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & "\RibbonUI"
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Dim Value As String
    If Ribbon Is Nothing Then
        Open Path For Input As #File
        Input #File, Value
        Close #File
        CopyMemory Ribbon, CLng(Value), 4
    End If
End Sub

' onload callback - set Ribbon object and store reference in temp file
Public Sub Ribbon_onLoad(ByVal RibbonUI As IRibbonUI)
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & "\RibbonUI"
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Open Path For Output As #File
    Print #File, ObjPtr(RibbonUI)
    Close #File
    Set Ribbon = RibbonUI
End Sub

Public Sub Example()
    getRibbon
    Ribbon.InvalidateControl "example"
End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS,

I'm going to try that tomorrow, but if I understand your "example" code correctly. this tests the presence of the ribbon in the workbook, and if it does not exist, it loads it from a file stored outside the excel workbook. I suppose it is an xml file, containing the xml code of the ribbon, and to generate this file, you would have to copy the code from the custom ui editor utility into notepad and save it with an extension. .xml

thank you for that clarification

Comment: It's a pointer not the actual ribbon. When excel opens, your ribbon is also loaded, the onload is called and you set `objRuban` so that VBA can interact with it. When the code editor stops `objRuban` is lost, all my code does is store and reload that reference if it becomes lost.

Comment: Also, if you don't have the onLoad defined in your XML like Eugene's answer explains then my code won't help.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I roughly understand how it works. if I'm not mistaken, the ribbon is loaded with the workbook, but to manipulate it with VBA you have to declare it once when it is loaded / Set Ribbon = RibbonUI / subsequently, the Ribbon object can be modified , and in this case in my case, with the following instruction / Ribbon.InvalidateControl "example" / which uses the BoolResult variable which goes from true to false depending on the context, make the "example" button accessible or not

Comment: I haven't found much documentation accessible at my level on handling the ribbon. Are there other possible interactions with the ribbon / Hide a tab, make it appear, Mark or make a group appear / activate a specific tab depending on the context ETC.